# References to unknown ordinance (Ord. 271, 6/8/1992)

Tags: pennsylvania, local-ordinance

I am still dealing with the enforcement of an in-town ordinance that is more than vague. (Pennsylvania, U.S.)

> E. The accumulation of heavy undergrowth and/or vegetation which would
>   impair the health and/or safety of the neighborhood; nor shall they
>   permit any trees, plants or shrubbery, or any portion thereof, to grow
>   on their property which constitute a safety hazard to pedestrian
>   and/or vehicular traffic. (Ord. 271, 6/8/1992)

All throughout the various ordinances and other township ordinances, I see the reference `(Ord. 271, 6/8/1992)`.

***Can anyone shed some light on this? What is it? Where is it?***

I have searched all the state law documents I have, which should be almost everything, and found nothing.

Comment: You have to give us a clue what town you're referring to. This occurs throughout the state.

Comment: @user6726 I did not think that was important since other townships have the same reference, however, I do get your point. It is Everett Pa. Specifically, I am looking at Chapter 10 Health and Safety though I think I have seen it in other chapters as well. You can find them here: http://everettpa.wixsite.com/home/ordinances Cheers!!

Comment: You probably have to go to city hall and look it up, since the council minutes are not available online. It looks like they passed a bunch or rules on that day, a different bunch on 8/10/87 when they passed 261, and so on. Ch 8 looks to have preceded this – Ord. 270,passed 11/12/1990.

Comment: @user6726 Cool! That makes sense. I am going to the courthouse tomorrow or the next and so I will check the law library. I have not been to our local law library but used to use the Montgomery County MD law library monthly. I hope it is open to the public. I will also be talking to a local lawyer on the vagueness of the code cited above. I am being told to do something that doesn't not exist in the law. I have to research things before ruining 80 year old hedges. Cheers!!